# What's the best way to check a list of 1 millions codes in Firebase/Cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase with Cloud function to test the good value of a code in a million pre-generated stored in Firebase Realtime Database.
It will be used in a mobile application to verify if a user have buy the bundle in real life.

**I found 2 working solutions**. In the first, I put the code directly in the name of the property. In the second I put the code in the child property called "key"
In the second case, the key parameter is *indexed*.

I need a fast (log n complexity) access to get the response.

Do you know if any of my solutions will work for about 1 million entries and 100 calls by second on Firebase.

(I am not familiar with NoSQL.)

In my sample, the codes are "ABCD-0000-000X"
(do not take the property called "user" in consideration)

**First Solution : Use the code value as parent**

[image: Solution 1]
Cloud Function source code

```
exports.checkKey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const code = req.query.code;

return admin.database().ref("Codes/" + code).once("value").then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
        return res.send("Invalid Code");
    }

    const nb = snapshot.child("nb");

    if (nb.val() > 4) {
        return res.send("NO more code");
    }

    snapshot.ref.update({ "nb": nb.val() + 1 });
    return res.send("OK");
});
```

**Second Solution : Use the code in child**

[image]

```
exports.getKey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code;

    var ref = admin.database().ref("Codes");
    ref.orderByChild("key").equalTo(code).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {

        const nb = snapshot.child("nb");

        if (nb.val() > 4) {
            return res.send("NOK");
        }

        snapshot.child("nb").set(nb.val() + 1);

        return res.send("OK");
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: "Can you help me to understand what happen in both case"  What don't you understand?    "what's is best solution for about 1 million entries and 100 calls by second."  Questions soliciting opinions are considered off-topic.

Comment: I edited my question.
I have 2 solutions, I just want help to find the good one for my problem. it's important for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you're going to be able to query a list of one million items. So storing the keys as a property named `key` is not going to work.

But if you keep the keys as the key of each item, means you can access the item by its path. And that scales really well.

So I'd go with your first approach.

That said: it's hard to recommend anything specific without knowing all use-cases, which nobody (including typically the project creator at an early stage) is likely to know. So I'd also recommend simply learning a bit more about NoSQL data modeling, by reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and by experimenting with various approaches before committing to any specific one.